# How do I update the textarea using useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a textarea array with values that can be updated. The text values in the array are updated when text is entered into the textarea. The array can also be updated externally.
The problem is that Textarea doesn't want to update its values with `setState()` like regular text does.

```
export function GameActions({}) {
  const [array, setArray] = useState<Type>([]);
  const changeText = (id: number, text: any) => {
    actions[id].text = text;
    setActions(actions);
  };

  return {actions.map((action, index) => (<Textarea
                          defaultValue={action.text}
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            changeText(index, e.currentTarget.value)
                          }
                        />))};
};
```

Comment: use `value` attribute rather than `defaultValue`.

Comment: `setActions(actions);`   actions never changes, it's always the same object.  You could try -> `setActions({...actions})` to clone it, then React will detect change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `actions` is an array state property, it should be:

```
setActions((actions)=>{
    return actions.map((act,i)=>{
        if(i == id) {
            act.text = text;
        }
        return act;
    });
});
```

When a state property is updated using its previous value, [the callback argument should be used](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Also, to update an element of a state array, `map` should be used, rather than the indexation operator `[]`.

Please read [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/), to learn how to update state arrays.